# Removing trailing numbers inside a column pandas

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a column with 25k + records containing similar information in the example data frame.

Example data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Address': ['Corner Great North Rd & Pipiwai Rd RD 6 Whangarei 2104',
                               '2305/142 Shakespeare Road Takapuna North Shore 0622',
                              '29 Stilwell Rd Mt Albert Auckland', '10/70 Atkinson Ave Otahuhu Auckland 1062']})
```

I'm trying to remove the trailing numbers in each record so ideally I would get a column that contains:

```
Address
--------
Corner Great North Rd & Pipiwai Rd RD 6 Whangarei
2305/142 Shakespeare Road Takapuna North Shore
29 Stilwell Rd Mt Albert Auckland
10/70 Atkinson Ave Otahuhu Auckland
```

I've tried using regex to remove all the characters at the end of string until it hits the first white space.

```
pattern = re.sub("(.*\s).*", '\\1', str)

df['Address'] = df.str.replace(pattern, '', regex=True)
```

This throws a TypeError exception which  I think is caused from the  numbers in the string. However I believe this code could also delete any trailing words deleting information I want to keep.

My question: Is there a regex pattern that could be applied for the entire column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `str.replace`:

```py
df['Address'] = df['Address'].str.replace(r'\s+\d+$', '')
```

The regex pattern `\s+\d+$` will match one or more whitespace characters followed by a number trailing to the end of the address.

Comment: Thank you. This solved the problem. In instances where this wouldn't work and threw the same TypeError exception, could that be due to special characters in the cell that the regex cant identify?

Comment: @LuiHellesoe If the above answer does not work in some cases, it means that the column value ends in something _other_ than whitespace followed by a trailing number.  Perhaps in these cases there is trailing whitespace beyond the number, or maybe the number has characters other than digits.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use [`rstrip()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.rstrip.html) and remove the trailing digits:

```
df['Address'] = df['Address'].str.rstrip(' 0123456789') # removed an additional trailing space
```

Prints:

```
df
Out[196]: 
                                             Address
0  Corner Great North Rd & Pipiwai Rd RD 6 Whanga...
1    2305/142 Shakespeare Road Takapuna North Shore 
2                  29 Stilwell Rd Mt Albert Auckland
3                10/70 Atkinson Ave Otahuhu Auckland
```